# R: Print two tables with xtable ()

Tags: r, sweave

I have data tables (d1 and d2) which I would like to print side by side or on top of each other in latex with their own individual titles. Is it possible to do that directly with `xtable()`? The two tables should be distinct, i.e. we could call them **Table x(a)** and **Table x(b)**, but they should be either adjacent, or stacked.

Comment: As one table? Then `xtable(rbind(d1,d2))` or `xtable(cbind(d1,d2))` should be fine right?

Comment: If you would like to keep the tables separate as Xa and Xb, then this becomes more of a latex labelling question. One of the moderators here should be able to migrate your question.

Comment: @SachaEpskamp `rbind` only works if both tables have the same `ncol` (or for `cbind` / `nrow`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend saving the results as two separate tables in different files (see the `file=` option to `print.xtable()`), and then `input` them into your LaTeX document with any command you find appropriate for your layout (`tabular`, `subfloat`, `minipage`, etc.). This is what I do in general, although I generally rely on LaTeX facilities in the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package. Should you want only to print them as a standalone PDF, use the `standalone` class for your document.

So, here is an example:

```
data(tli)
fm1 <- aov(tlimth ~ sex + ethnicty + grade + disadvg, data=tli)
print(xtable(fm1), file="ta.tex", floating=FALSE)
print(xtable(head(tli, n=5)), file="tb.tex", floating=FALSE)
```

then, a quick tex wrapper (compile with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Table x(a)]{\label{tab:tab1a}\scalebox{.5}{\input{./ta}}}\quad
\subfloat[Table x(b)]{\label{tab:tab1b}\scalebox{.5}{\input{./tb}}}
\caption{Caption about here}
\label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Remove the `\scalebox` command for default (stacked) layout, unless they are narrow enough to fit at their default size, as noted by @David.

[image]

Comment: @chi removing `\scalebox` does not stack tables if they are narrow enough to fit at their default size.

Comment: @David Ah, I think you're just right. Updated my response accordingly!

Answer (score 10):

See [Alan Munn's answer to a similar question on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36358/4821).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\title{Side-by-side xtables}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
First some R code to create some data.
<<>>=
myData <- matrix(c(19,89,23,23,74,44,16,39,67),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(myData) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(myData) <- c("1","2","3")
myData2 <- myData * 2
@

Now we place the data in two side-by-side tables:

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
library("xtable")
print(xtable(myData),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@
\captionof{table}{The first table}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
print(xtable(myData2),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData2)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@
\captionof{table}{The second table}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]