# Side by side Xtables in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr

I have seen answers to creating side by side xtables in RMarkdown-HTML
[knitr, R Markdown, and xtable: xtable tables within HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397407/knitr-r-markdown-and-xtable-xtable-tables-within-html-table)

and how to create side by side xtables in Sweave directly
[R: Print two tables with xtable ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263394/r-print-two-tables-with-xtable)

But how about side by side xtables in Rmarkdown/Pandoc?

In my *Rmd file I have

````
```{r , results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
female.bmi <- lm(bmi ~ AGEGROUP + RACE + GEO_SPA + FPL_FIN + as.factor(year),
              data=lach[lach$GENDER=='Female',] )
xtable(female.bmi, comment=FALSE, caption = 'Linear regression of BMI for females')
male.bmi <- lm(bmi ~ AGEGROUP + RACE + GEO_SPA + FPL_FIN + as.factor(year),
            data=lach[lach$GENDER=='Male',] )
xtable(male.bmi, comment=FALSE, caption = 'Linear regression of BMI for males')
```
````

then I compile as follows:

```
knit('Modeling/simple.rmd', 'Modeling/simple.md') # creates md file
pandoc('Modeling/simple.md', format='latex') # LaTeX/PDF
```

These show up as separate tables - good! But how can I get them to display as side by side subfigures/subtables? I've tried to integrate Latex subfigure code around the `{r}print(xtable)` code to no avail.

Comment: Could not find object "lach" dude :P

Comment: Sorry, I know I didn't provide a working example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok it is very easy to produce it using R markdown. Below is my code and result:

I combined the example you linked to:

This is the code of `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: " 2 tables in markdown side by side"
author: "Marcin Kosiński"
date: "2014"
output: 
   pdf_document:
      includes:
         in_header: header2.tex
      highlight: pygments
      toc: true
      toc_depth: 3
      number_sections: true
---

```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment="", message=FALSE,tidy.opts=list(keep.blank.line=TRUE, width.cutoff=120),options(width=100), cache=TRUE,fig.align='center',fig.height=6, fig.width=10,fig.path='figure/beamer-',fig.show='hold',size='footnotesize', cache=TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(xtable)
data(tli)
attach(tli)
x <- tli
fm1 <- aov(tlimth ~ sex + ethnicty + grade + disadvg, data=x)
print(xtable(fm1), file="ta.tex", floating=FALSE)
print(xtable(head(tli, n=5)), file="tb.tex", floating=FALSE)
```

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Table x(a)]{\label{tab:tab1a}\scalebox{.5}{\input{./ta}}}\quad
\subfloat[Table x(b)]{\label{tab:tab1b}\scalebox{.5}{\input{./tb}}}
\caption{Caption about here}
\label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}
````

And here is a code of `header2.tex` file that need to be in the same folder as `.Rmd` file:

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Wow interesting. I learned more than a few things from your response. I don't know yet if it'll actually work (especially since I think I've converted to Rstudio instead of *rmd +pandoc) --but-- very helpful post regardless. Thank you for your detailed response.

Comment: Thanks - this was very useful!  I do want to point out you have `cache = TRUE` twice in the options line.  I had removed one, and I couldn't figure out why things weren't updating! :D

Comment: This doesn't work in HTML. Any suggestion how to achieve the same result in HTML?

Comment: Yes because xtables are for latex/pdf output :)
If you creat a separate question with that and post here a link to it, then I'll try to help you out.

Comment: `xtable` is for html output too, but yes, totally separate answer.

Comment: @MarcinKosiński I'm playing around with caption placement with this method, but have not had any success adding `caption.placement = ` to the `print` call.  Any thoughts?  Not a latex expert.

Comment: @Clayton can you open additional issue for that? and leave here a link to it?

Comment: This is great. But how do you align those two tables vertically (top-align) - when they are of unequal row numbers. I am very happy to open a new question for that.