# How to get sans serif font for xtable in PDFs?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

Is there any straightforward solution to get a sans serif font in rmarkdown PDF tables? The font in normal text, code, and equations should stay unchanged. I'm demanding on `xtables`.

**Example:**

````
---
title: ''
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)
```

```{r ranking tradeoff, results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(mtcars[1:2, ])
      , include.rownames=TRUE
      , comment=FALSE
      )
```
````

The text in the table should appear in sans serif.

[image: rif]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50542024/6574038) solution but it didn't work for me. The fonts were not found, albeit the [powershell font check](https://superuser.com/a/760632/788591) turned out differently. However the fonts are named e.g. "Liberation Sans" and not "LiberationSans". Hence I tried to specify `sansfont: "Liberation Sans"` without success. Also there appears to be a package clash `asmath` vs `mathtools` when using `xelatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new environment for the font and use it with the `latex.environments` option of `print.xtable`.

````
\newenvironment{myfont}{\sffamily}{}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)
```

```{r ranking tradeoff, results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(mtcars[1:2, ])
      , include.rownames=TRUE
      , comment=FALSE
      , latex.environments = "myfont"
      )
```
````

Comment: This works great with minimum effort, thanks! However, one of my tables are two xtables side by side, where this solution won't work. Do you know a way to extend it to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414213/6574038), or perhaps something that would work?

Comment: @jay.sf I would try to put `\sffamily` just after `\begin{table}[ht]`.